# I'm sending a get request from Angular service to Online REST API and gets in return 0 - {"isTrusted":true}

Tags: angular2-services

I'm sending a get request from Angular service to Online REST API and gets in return 0 - {"isTrusted":true}
What is wrong? Is it connected to CORS? How to solve it?

Here's the code:

// Promise Version

```
import { Injectable }              from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response }          from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { User } from './user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  // URL to web api
 private usersUrl = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  getUsers (): Promise<User[]> {

    return this.http.get(this.usersUrl)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

---

```
 private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }

  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    ---
  }
  }
```

Thanks...

Comment: what is the http response code in the network tab of your devloper console? If it is 403(forbidden) then your are probably right about it being a CORS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally discovered the problem: The request in question returns mixed content which is blocked by default in Firefox.

To fix this problem I use HTTPS instead of HTTP:

This: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
should be: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'